# Python: unable to open two identical files in Windows

Tags: python

I have a file located in a certain folder.

```
string1 = 'E:/SenseableCloud/Emanuele/Projects/SEIR1/SEIR1/sf/data_0.0100_3.50_0.7_0.3_0.010000/run_0.csv'

a = pd.read_csv(string1)
```

and it works. Then I have another the same identical string in another loop and as the following

```
string2 = 'E:/SenseableCloud/Emanuele/Projects/SEIR1/SEIR1/sf/data_0.0010_3.50_0.7_0.3_0.010000/run_0.csv'
b = pd.read_csv(string2)
```

I have the following error:

```
IOError: File E:/SenseableCloud/Emanuele/Projects/SEIR1/SEIR1/sf/data_0.0010_3.50_0.7_0.3_0.010000/run_0.csv does not exist
```

Comment: Are the permissions identical? File ownership?

Comment: Yes, same folder, same machine.

Comment: Do you mean "two identical files", or do you think you're trying to open the _same_ file in two different places? Because those filenames are not identical

Comment: The file is the same in the same folder

Comment: The second filename is different from the first. This looks like a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same, 
the first has 'data_0.0100' in it, where the other has 'data_0.0010'.
I used

```
string1 = 'E:/SenseableCloud/Emanuele/Projects/SEIR1/SEIR1/sf/data_0.0100_3.50_0.7_0.3_0.010000/run_0.csv'
string2 = 'E:/SenseableCloud/Emanuele/Projects/SEIR1/SEIR1/sf/data_0.0010_3.50_0.7_0.3_0.010000/run_0.csv'

print(string1 == string2)
```

and the result was

```
False
```